# How to eliminate obstacles on the lane for autonomous vehicle?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I work on a autonomous vehicle project. I want to determine steering angle of the car on a highway. But for this specific scenario, there are no lane lines or any lane boundary, only the asphalt itself. I assume that the surroundings won't contain any color close enough to the asphalt color.

(Assume that there is no white line in the middle, all I see if asphalt)

[image]

The process is real time (on Raspberry Pi) and frames are captured by the help of a camera.

For this problem, I proposed a pipeline as follows (OpenCV 4.0 with C++):

- Denoise --> BGR2HSV --> HSV Filter --> Canny Edge Detection --> Crop to ROI --> Hough Line Detection --> Process lines

This pipeline clearly gives me the how car should steer in order to stay in the middle of the one-way lane. I can filter the asphalt section with HSV. The problem is when there are obstacles on the lane. There might be boxes placed on the side or middle of the lane. In this case HSV filter creates a big black box on the lane. Hough line detection transforms the edges of the box into false lane lines. Eventually, this leads to wrong steering prediction. Actually, I developed an algorithm to handle this problem by observing slopes of the hough lines, however, it is not always stable.

(A red box placed on the side of the lane)

[image]

My point is, would you suggest any improvement on this process to eliminate possible obstacles on image filtering? Obstacles on the lane lead to false hough lines and affect steering decision. An improvement I thought is that detecting the indices of maximum white pixel counts from left and right of the image (in ROI), then setting every pixel between to white. This would sweep out the obstacles that are in the middle of the road (vehicle can hit to obstacle) but leaves the ones in the side of the lane anyways. But if the road bends, this won't be practical, because the improvement will lose the bending data in the image.

(image source: https://www.masterbuilder.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Rs-46000-cr-initiative-taken-for-new-express-highways-elevated-roads-Govt.png)

**EDIT:**

When I use convexHull [as in OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html), I get the following result, which is unexpected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you've applied the HSV-filter, you can use findContours followed by [convexHull](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#convex-hull). This bridges 'gaps' in the detected contour.

Example:
[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# load image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('hull.png',0)
# load image in color
img_color = cv2.imread('hull.png')
# find contours
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# get and draw convexhull
for cnt in contours:
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
    cv2.drawContours(img_color,[hull],0,(0,0,255),3)
# show images
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.imshow('Result', img_color)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For a more realistic example, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55894409/10699171). The described process is applied in there:
[image]

Comment: I checked convexHull, and applied it on a sample figure. Could you check the EDIT in the main question @J.D. ? Actually the result is unsatisfying.

Comment: Could you also include the input image?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of identifying the road and trying to eliminating external objects like boxes, you can try locating the middle of the road (w or w/o the random object) and calculate the steering angle from there.

Here's a research paper doing it this way which also helps when the lane is there but not visible when there is poor lighting or shadow obstructing the lane.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282921028_Steering_angle_estimation_for_autonomous_vehicle_navigation_using_hough_and_Euclidean_transform

Answer (score 1):

One trick Tesla uses, **if, for any reason, the lanes are not visible** is to follow the front vehicle's movement. So, instead of eliminating the obstacles, You can take advantage of them, with the appropriate algorithm.

Your algorithm should look like this:

1. Try to detect the lane you are moving on.
2. If front vehicle is found, then track the front vehicle, using a motion tracking algorithm for the front vehicle.

This article makes a good introduction in object tracking in python:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/30/opencv-object-tracking/

If you'd like to learn more about Autonomous Vehicles, You can check out my github repository here:

https://github.com/kochlisGit/autonomous-vehicles-deep-reinforcement-learning